# Server Side code in WCF RIA services doesn't execk

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

Im new to silverlight business application . Ive got problem with my server side code. Ive created such code in .Web app

```
public class Doc
{
    public Doc() { }
    public Doc(Guid ID, Guid ProjektId, string Name)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.ProjektID = ProjektID;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjektID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


}
// TODO: Create methods containing your application logic.
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class DocList : DomainService
{
    [Query]
    public List<Doc> getDocList()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Testuje debugera dokument");
        //getImlArray();
        List<Doc> docList = new List<Doc>();

        docList.Add(new Doc(Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty, "t1"));
        docList.Add(new Doc(Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty, "t21"));
        docList.Add(new Doc(Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty, "t211"));
        return docList;
    }
    [Insert]
    public void emptyInsert(Doc project) { }

    [Update]
    public void emptyUpdater(Doc project) { }

    [Delete]
    public void emptyDelete(Doc project) { }

}
```

In client app in view a call for something like this:
    public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        this.Title = ApplicationStrings.HomePageTitle;
        //.net reflektor
        //DocList docList = new DocList();
        //docList.getDocListQuery();

        DocList x = new DocList();
        x.getDocListQuery();
   }
```

The problem is that my server side code isn't call. Its not a debuger problem because even the `Debug.WriteLine("Testuje debugera dokument")` isnt display in the output section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve it.Silly mistake of a beginner. I havent used LoadOperation in my silverlight app